# SEVERE: Servlet /JAXRS-HelloWorld threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey, restful-url

I read through plenty of posts related to this issue but couldn't get any help .

ERROR
Appreciate if someone can help me out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br4jd.png)

This is how my POM and web looks like . I have tried copying the required war file to C:\appache tomcat 7 but no luck. Even deploying it within the eclipse also gives me the same error.

WEb
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE7Wr.png)

POM.xML:-

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tutorialacademy.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>helloworld Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>  
 <repository>  
  <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>  
  <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>  
  <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>  
  <layout>default</layout>  
 </repository>  
</repositories>  

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
               </configuration>
          </plugin>


        </plugins>

    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: The images are the same... Anyway, don't post images of the error or of the code. Edit your question adding the error message and the code as text properly formatted.

Comment: I can see in the image you are using Apache Tomcat 7.0.x. I also can see you have a web.xml declaring the Servlet API as 3.1. Be aware that **Tomcat 7.0.x supports Servlet API 3.0**. More information in [Apache Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the exception, it looks like the [`com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/servlet/ServletContainer.html) class is not available in your classpath.

Note that *Jersey 1.x* and *Jersey 2.x* use different package names:

- Jersey 1.x: `com.sun.jersey`
- Jersey 2.x: `org.glassfish.jersey`

So, I understand you are using **Jersey 1.x**.

### Jersey 1.x depencency

To use *Jersey 1.x*, you need the following dependecy in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

To read more about Jersey 1.x dependencies, have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/chapter_deps.html).

You can check the latest version of the `jersey-server` `artifactId` in the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server).

### Jersey 2.x depencency

If you want to use *Jersey 2.x*, you have to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, 
         use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

You can check the latest version of the `jersey-container-servlet` `artifactId` in the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet).

Read more about Jersey 2.x dependencies in the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html).

---

### UPDATE

If you can, I do recommend using *Jersey 2.x* rather than *Jersey 1.x*.

To do it, use the following `pom.xml`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tutorialacademy.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Hello World</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>  
        <repository>  
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>  
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>  
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>  
            <layout>default</layout>  
        </repository>  
    </repositories>  

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, 
                 use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And the following `web.xml`:

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

</web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i crossed checked it and changed the server tempate to 3.0 as i am using apache tomcat. Inspite of this i still get the same error. Please suggest what can be done next .

Comment: @user1007451 I wish I had a crystal ball to know how your `pom.xml` looks like. But I don't have. So, please edit your question and post your `pom.xml`. The images you attached are all the same.

Comment: @user1007451 My advice is: remove all Jersey 1.x dependencies and add Jersey 2.x depencencies.

Comment: Appreciate your response, i have added the POM.XML too

Comment: This is the example which i am following it                                    http://tutorial-academy.com/restful-webservice-jersey-maven/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help . However, i am started getting a different error now , this is what i see "The requested resource is not available " http://localhost:8080/helloworld/rest/ wherein if i check for localhost i see the apache web page . looks like something is wrong, i tried removing my war file and removing the server and adding a fresh one but still sees the same issue .  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make a Web application to provide web service using Jersey library in Tomcat and Eclipse and still getting problem after adding jersey-server.jar in the classpath. You can follow these steps to add dependency on deployment assembly.

Project -> properties -> development assembly -> add -> java build path entries -> maven dependency

This should work.